# How to Convert Year-Week to Year-Month-Day in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there an efficient way or function to convert the week of the year to a datetime object? For example, if I had "2018-03", how would I be able to convert it to "2018-01-21"? (The third week of the year would correspond to the third week of the year, January 21st).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

consider below as an option

```
select year_week, 
  date_add(
    date(cast(split(year_week, '-')[offset(0)] as int64), 1, 1),
    interval cast(split(year_week, '-')[offset(1)] as int64) * 7 - 1 day
  ) date
from data
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Comment: @boba - have you tried?